# webdriver browser.acceptAlert() not closing the browser alert

Tags: javascript, webdriver-io

Using webdriver.io, our tests have:

```
afterEach(async () => {
    browser.execute('window.localStorage.clear()');
    browser.deleteAllCookies();
    browser.execute('sessionStorage.clear()');
    browser.refresh();
    console.log(await browser.isAlertOpen());
    browser.pause(3000);
    browser.acceptAlert();
});
```

The `browser.refresh();` prompts an alert:

[image]

Neither

```
    console.log(await browser.isAlertOpen());
```

or

```
    browser.acceptAlert();
```

do anything. The alert stays open and the next `it(...` test cannot proceed.

Help appreciated.

**Edit**

Using:

```
afterEach(async () => {
  browser.execute('window.localStorage.clear()');
  await browser.deleteAllCookies();
  await browser.execute(() => {
    window.localStorage.clear();
    window.sessionStorage.clear();
    window.beforeunload = (ev) => { 
      ev.stopImmediatePropagation(); };
      window.addEventListener("beforeunload", (ev) => {
      ev.stopImmediatePropagation();
    });
  });
  await browser.url('/');
});
```

there is an error running the webdriver test:

> Timeout of 60000ms exceeded. The execution in the test "after each" hook took too long.

Answer (score 4):

I have a feeling this is the same as in https://github.com/webdriverio/webdriverio/discussions/7191. That this is not an "alert" in the sense of being created by `window.alert`. It's the browser's action when unloading a page that registered a callback to the `beforeunload` event.

There's [a Google Chrome-specific workaround there](https://github.com/webdriverio/webdriverio/discussions/7191#discussioncomment-1086281) (provided by Erwin Heitzman) to disable that kind of popup:

> ```js
> capabilities: [{
>   browserName: 'chrome',
>   'goog:chromeOptions': {
>     prefs: {
>       'profile.managed_default_content_settings.popups' : 1,
>       'profile.managed_default_content_settings.notifications' : 1,
>     }
>   }
> }]
> ```

Or you could unregister the `beforeunload` callback/listener or try to neuter it with [one of the workarounds provided](https://github.com/webdriverio/webdriverio/discussions/7191#discussioncomment-7765897) by Christian Bromann or Slava Nikulin:

> ```js
> await browser.execute(() => {
>   window.beforeunload = () => {}
> })
> // or
> browser.scriptAddPreloadScript({
>   functionDeclaration: `window.beforeunload = () => {}`
> })
> // or
> setInterval(() => {
>   window.addEventListener('beforeunload', e => {
>     e.stopImmediatePropagation();
>   });
> }, intervalMillis)
> ```

Comment: Thanks, adjusting the capabilities did not work, and using those extra functions didn't work in the `afterEach` hook.